# add a unique, case-insensitive index to a h2 column

Tags: sql, constraints, h2

Is there a way to create a unique case-insensitive index on a column in a [H2](https://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) table?
For what it's worth, I can do this in Postgres with:

```
create unique index unique_name_idx on my_table (UPPER(name));
```

Comment: Perhaps VARCHAR_IGNORECASE data type, and a unique index?

Comment: @jarlh I think your solution is better than mine. It should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

H2 only allows bona fide table columns as index components. It does not allow expressions in them as PosgreSQL and other higher end database engines do.

However, you can index a computed column as a workaround. For example:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  uname varchar(20) as upper(name)
);

create unique index ix1 on t (uname);

insert into t (id, name) values
  (1, 'Chicago'),
  (2, 'Montreal'),
  (3, 'Monterrey');
```

Then, if you try to insert:

```
insert into t (id, name) values
  (4, 'montreal');
```

It fails as expected:

> Error: Unique index or primary key violation: "IX1 ON PUBLIC.T(UNAME) VALUES ('MONTREAL', 2)"; SQL statement:
> insert into t (id, name) values
> (4, 'montreal') [23505-197]
> SQLState:  23505
> ErrorCode: 23505

Additionally, the index is also used for searching information. For example, the following `SELECT` uses the index as expected:

```
explain plan for
select uname from t where uname = 'MONTREAL';
```

Execution Plan:

```
SELECT
    UNAME
FROM PUBLIC.T
    /* PUBLIC.IX1: UNAME = 'MONTREAL' */
WHERE UNAME = 'MONTREAL'
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider altering the column data type to `VARCHAR_IGNORECASE` (a case insensitive version of VARCHAR):

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN name VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(20);
```

Then you can simply do:

```
create unique index unique_name_idx on my_table (name);
```

http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#varchar_ignorecase_type